# Meaning of ! and . while accessing objects and properties

Tags: ms-access, vba

While programming in MS Access, there are certain places where an object is referred by `!` operator and its property by `.` operator.

For example,

```
Forms![Form Name].Visible
```

I was just wondering, is there any specific way to know what is what? I mean how can we be sure if `!` is to be used or `.` is to be used?

Also, is there any specific reason, why two different symbols are used for objects and properties?

Comment: See notes re Michael Kaplans's reponse here: http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-access/archive/2008/05/30/dot-or-bang.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A period is always used for properties & methods.
ex: `recordset.MoveNext`

An exclamation mark is used for child objects. The most common child object you will use is the field of a table.
ex: `recordset!fieldname = "John"`

In your example above, [Form Name] is a form that is a child of the forms set (which includes all forms). The [] is used for objects with spaces.

**Warning**: Access is fairly tolerant and will often allow a period to be used instead of an exclamation mark.
ex: `recordset.fieldname = "John"`
It's bad coding, but I give the example so you won't be confused when you see it.

Comment: It is not bad coding to say frm.MyControl, it takes advantage of intellisense and is widely used. I think your explanation is a little on the short side.